# When using a swiftui picker with an array of options. How can I save the selected option rather than the index value to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: arrays, firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'd like to be able to access and use the location. Currently only the index value from the picker is being saved to Cloud Firestore.

Here is the picker:

```
Picker(selection: $viewModel.injury.locationIndex, label: Text("General Location")) {
  ForEach(0 ..< locationOptions.count) {
    Text(self.locationOptions[$0])
}
```

Here is the array:

```
var locationOptions = [" Head", " Chest", " Right Arm", " Left Arm", " Right Hand", "✋ Left Hand", " Waist", " Right Leg", " Left Leg", " Right Foot", " Left Foot"]
```

The locationIndex is successfully uploaded to Cloud Firestore:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class InjuryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var injury: Injury = Injury(id: "", userId: "", specificLocation: "", comment: "", active: false, injuryDate: Date(), exercises: "", locationIndex: 0)
    
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func addInjury(injury: Injury) {
        
        do{
            var addedInjury = injury
            addedInjury.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let _ = try db .collection("injuries").addDocument(from: addedInjury)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func save () {
        addInjury(injury: injury)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection and identifier of Picker have to be same type. So you would have something like

```
Picker(selection: $viewModel.injury.specificLocation, label: Text("General Location")) {
  ForEach(locationOptions, id: \.self) {
    Text($0)
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks so much 